# BinaryReader dispose after function scope

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, garbage-collection

Just wanted to verify I will not have any handle leaks and all..
I have the following method

```
public static MyObject DoSomething(Stream MyStream)
{
     var br = new BinaryReader(MyStream);
     return DoMoreThings(br);                    
}
```

I create `MyStream` outside..is it safe to say that after this function `br` will safely be collected by GC? I don't explicitly dispose it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it will be collected by the garbage collector eventually, it's a rather bad practice to leave it there uncollected.

You can ensure that it's cleaned up by wrapping it in a `using`:

```
using (var br = new BinaryReader(MyStream))
{
    return DoMoreThings(br);
}
```

The only drawback here is that the `using` means that it will call `br.Dispose`, which among other things will close the underlying stream: `MyStream` in this case. You can prevent that by calling the [overloaded constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712804%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), telling it to leave the stream open:

```
using (var br = new BinaryReader(MyStream, Encoding.UTF8, true))
```

Replace the `Encoding.UTF8` with whatever encoding matches the strings in your file. `Encoding.UTF8` is the default used by the constructor that doesn't take an Encoding parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It will be eventually, but you should type it like this instead

```
using(var br = new BinaryReader(MyStream))
{
     return DoMoreThings(br);
}
```

`Using` statement is a syntactic sugar on try..finally block, firing `Dispose` method. All objects implementing `IDisposable` interface should be disposed manually.

Comment: It depends on what `DoMoreThings(br)` does with the reader, if whatever it returns needs to still access the reader you should not dispose of it, instead the object that is being returned should be `IDisposeable` and disposing of the returned object should dispose the internal reader.

Comment: I did it! but it closed MyStream which I was needed after this function...this is why I can't really use using here..what do you say?

Comment: @user1025852 use `using(var br = new BinaryReader(MyStream, new UTF8Encoding(), true))` and the `BinaryReader` will not close your `Stream`.

Comment: Great! I wasn't aware of that option, appreciate it.